# HyperLink address not getting added in Numbers using ApachePOI when protocol is different from http

Tags: java, macos, apache-poi

### Code Snippet

```
  int rowNum = 1;
  Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
  Hyperlink href = createHelper.createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL);
 
  CellStyle hlink_style = workbook.createCellStyle();
  Font hlink_font = workbook.createFont();
  hlink_font.setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE);
  hlink_font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
  hlink_style.setFont(hlink_font);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("URL Link");
  Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL);
  link.setAddress("myProtocol/someText");
  cell.setHyperlink(link);
  cell.setCellStyle(hlink_style);
```

if i print cell.getHyperlink().getAddress() , it is giving me correct value what i have set , but once execution is over and when i check the Numbers Sheet the url is not clickable and when i check in Format - > Add link , there is no link added at all

Note: Same script works if i use say "https://www.google.com"

Comment: For me this code works using `apache poi 4.1.2`. It creates a hyperlink to address "myProtocol\someText" which, of course, cannot be followed then. But the link is there for me.

Comment: i tried but. no luck

Answer (score 1):

well this solves the above problem

```
 cell.setCellFormula("HYPERLINK(\"myProtocol/someValue\", \"myLink\")");
```